# Asking some method in flask-peewee

Tags: flask, peewee

I have found the method `get_flashed_messages()` in base.html (from [example](https://github.com/coleifer/flask-peewee/blob/master/example/templates/base.html) tweet app of flask-peewee):

```
</div>
  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
<h2>{% block content_title %}{% endblock %}</h2>
```

My question is, where in the code base is `get_flashed_messages()` defined?

Second question is: Is there another example showing query result in templates in flask? or flask-peewee similar to in this [tutorial](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#expressions)?.

Answer (score 0):

Flask has built in message flashing--see an example [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/flashing/). The function `get_flashed_messages()` is available when you import flash like this:

```
from flask import flash
```